# Chrome extension declarativeNetRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently working on migrating a chrome extension from manifest_version 2 to v3. I did most of the changes but I am stuck with declarativeNetRequest. There is a scenario where we need to redirect the user based on the URL pattern.
For Ex: when a use click on the app in the extension popup and the URL is let's say https://xyxinc.xyx.com/start/12345 then it should be transformed to https://xyxinc.xyx.com/start/12345?plugin=3.1.1
and when the app has passed the authentication phase then it will be automatically moved to the respective app URL which is being handled automatically.

There are two problems I am facing here:

1. When I am clicking on the app in the portal then I am not getting how to get the URL of the app i.e., https://xyxinc.xyx.com/start/12345 as it was pretty handy to get the url in the callback passed to webRequest API but in decalarativeNetRequest we don't have such feature.
2. Will the rule kicks in always as we navigate to the URLs or it will be applied only once at the beginning? If it is applied once then how can I redirect the user when there are dynamic redirect URLs.
3. Also, for manifest v3 can we use declarativeNetRequest and webRequest APIs together as per use cases or only the declarativeNetRequest will be applicable?

Please help me as I tried searching over internet but didn't get accurate information

Thnaks in advance

Comment: Use ["redirect" with "queryTransform"](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#type-URLTransform) and chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules to toggle the rules on demand.

Comment: yeah but how to get the current URL. I have few more doubts with chrome extension. Can we please connect over any meeting app that you might like and discuss this further. I am in a kind of emergency and really in dire need of help.

Comment: There's no need to "get the URL", see the examples for declarativeNetRequest + redirect.

Comment: I tried the above approach but instead of transforming the URL it is blocking it.

Comment: It means you did it incorrectly. Show your code.

Comment: const RULES = [{id: 1,priority: 2,action: {type: "redirect",redirect: {transform: {queryTransform: {addOrReplaceParams: [{ key: "plugin_version", value: extensionVersionString }]}}}},condition: {
        urlFilter: "/client/apps/select/*",
        resourceTypes: ["main_frame"]
      }
    },
  ];

here is the Rule definition, after observing it I found out that the url is indeed getting replaced to what I wanted but it is not opening the page. It is just showing block message on the screen

Comment: **<domain> is blocked.**  
**This page has been blocked by an extension.**  
**Try disabling your extensions.**  
**ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT**  

Here, domain name is replaced with actual domain for the extension.

Comment: Apparently you have an old rule when you experimented with the API. Either remove them or uninstall the extension and install it again.

Comment: I already removed all the previous rules and just kept this one. I tried reinstalling as well but still it is same.

Comment: Not simply reinstalling, but uninstalling and installing again. It would also help removing `_metadata` folder manually in the extension's directory. Also, maybe it's another extension - see if this happens after you uninstall your extension?

Comment: I am using load unpacked for this extension as I am working locally.

Comment: My comment still applies fully. Make sure you followed all the suggestions exactly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257139/discussion-between-sumit-and-woxxom).